# Does Joomla Host Value under Server Database setting needs a change after change in ip address

Tags: database

need help. My web hosting recently sent email that they will perform an infrastructure upgrade and migrate my Cloud account to a new server with the latest hardware in Google facility.

They now migtrated website to Google facility (remained and managed by present host only) and in this changed old ip address to new ip address

Post successful migration they confirmed through email - that they have automatically updated domain's DNS settings and no action is required on my behalf.

My Query is
As the migration is just been done and IP address been changed from Old IP to New IP and site working absolutely fine.

I need to know that in Joomla there is a setting in global configuration - server - database setting where host is referred as old ip address value. Does same also need to be changed to New IP Address as shared

As of now with Old Ip address in global configuration - server - database setting - host value with old ip address site working absolutely fine

Do i still need to punch in New Ip address value in host setting, Reiterating site working absolutely fine with old ip address in host value

spoken to host, as per them its joomla query and best to ask or get help in this joomla forum. Can any one guide or confirm

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the `configuration.php` file for specific IP addresses is probably a reasonable and sufficient precaution if you have reason to be concerned.

In practice, and especially with shared hosting, server settings are usually set to "localhost" in the `configuration.php` file so there is no need to update any IP addresses in Joomla when moving to a new server.

After a move, you should check in Global Configuration that the log and tmp paths are correct. (If the Log and Temp folders show as writeable at System -> System Information - Folder Permissions then these are probably fine).

The only other change I sometimes have to do after a move is changing the default output directory in Akeeba Backup.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a dedicated IP Address and is on cloud hosting. Checked Log and TMp folder and they are writeable and correct. The directory and path everything remains same, only is that my hosting moved to another server and is now on google server with a different ip. Although site working absolutely fine with old ip in host and when logged in with new ip through cpanel too, the database is getting updated too. Unsure if its a temporary phenomenon and i in end need to change ip in host setting in joomla administrator or not

Comment: If configuration.php is set to "localhost" then Joomla is running on that server. As long as your name server records are correct then you shouldn't have to worry about anything else unless you have a CDN enabled or other complications.

Comment: indeed localhost was what needed to be mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Yes, update the IP to the new IP. Your website (Joomla files) may be getting served by the new server, but the database behind it is being sourced from the old server.

If the site breaks with the new IP, revert your change in configuration.php and speak to your host to get the correct hostname or IP for the new server.

Comment: Thanks, its a big site with almost 200 people at same time. will see to check it at lean period of day.